# Ionic app not being served from "ionic://localhost/" on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, cocoapods, ionic4

Been working on an Ionic app, the app runs well on Android, however when adding push notification services the app simply shows a blank screen after the splash screen and doesn't load the app from **"ionic://localhost/"** instead loads from **"file://"** after removing the push service the app works well again on all platforms.

We are using the cordova-plugin-firebasex  plugin for push notifications.
The error from Xcode when running the app is: "Failed to load webpage with error:...."

Comment: Are you using [`cordova-plugin-ionic-webview`](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview)? If not, try installing it.

Comment: yes, the cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1 plugin is being used